Append URL parameters from the session storage
I have an Email where there is a call to action, which forwards them to my site with some parameters
On that page, I just want the parameters are stored in session (This works already using a JS script) but later they can visit to "Contact Form" page on my site where it requires them to fill their basic info (like name, email etc). To improve user efficiency, I need that URL parameters are filled in even if they are on different page of my same website like:
> Ex:
> 
> www.test.com/Page1?language=de&var_FirstName=Marc
> www.test.com/Page2?language=de&var_FirstName=Marc
> www.test.com/Page3?language=de&var_FirstName=Marc

I want that the parameters are always appended in the end, so that no matter where they go around in the site, so once they visit to my "Contact Form" page, they do not need to fill in the info.
I already tried to store the parameters and it now shows in session storage. But, when I visit to "contact form" page, I do not see obviously nothing.
